# When will $1$ dollar equal $1$ yen?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

> Suppose the value of \$1 in Japanese yen decreases at 2% per year. Starting from \$1 = Y240, when will $1$ dollar equal $1$ yen?

The equation should be $240e^{-0.02t}=1$, which gives $t=50\ln240$. But the key says something different: $t=\frac{\ln(1/240)}{\ln(.98)}$. My calculator tells me that my answer is $274$ years but the key is $271$ years. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Indeed, it ought to be $\log_{0.98}\frac1{240}$. If it decreases at 2 percent, then 98 percent will be the one remaining per year, no?

Comment: You seem to confuse the formula for _discrete_ time with the one for _continuous_ time. $e^{-0.02t}$ is in fact a formula for _continuous_ time, which is not the case in this problem. Instead, we should use $(1-0.02)^t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the value keeps decreasing by $2$%, that is, the value of the yen after one year is $98$% of the value it was in the previous year. Translating this mathematically, we can get $$\text{Value of Yen after one year} = Y_1 = 240\times \frac{98}{100}$$ Similarly, we can show that $$\text{Value of Yen after two years}= Y_2 = 240\times \left(\frac{98}{100}\right)^2$$ $$\Rightarrow \text{Value of Yen after n years} = Y_n = 240\times \left(\frac{98}{100}\right)^n$$ Now, we have $$Y_n = 1\implies 240\times \left(\frac{98}{100}\right)^n = 1$$ giving us, $$\left(\frac{98}{100}\right)^n =\frac{1}{240}$$ Taking $\log$ on both sides, $$n\log(0.98) = \log\left(\frac{1}{240}\right) \Rightarrow n=\frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{240}\right)}{\log 0.98} \approx 271 \text{years}$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you set up is incorrect:
As it decreases by $2$% each year it should read
$$240\times(1-0.02)^t=1$$
because at the end of each year its value will be $98$% of the value it started with.